# Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project proj2

Tags: plugins, sonarqube

We are using Sonarqube 5.6.6 and can no longer scan our projects successfully.

Versions:

```
SonarQube 5.6.6  
Java 1.8
```

We are executing using `mvn sonar:sonar`, and getting the below error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project proj2: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : 'D:\SCM\Checkout\file2.java': NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project proj2: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : 'D:\SCM\Checkout\file2.java'
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : 'D:\SCM\Checkout\RED_CSI2_Sonarqube_Scan\code\csi-core-data\src\main\java\com\redplc\csi\coredata\dao\hibernate\user\UserDaoHibernate.java'
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:65)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : 'D:\SCM\Checkout\file2.java'
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:105)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.scan(JavaAstScanner.java:68)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanSources(JavaSquid.java:119)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:113)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.execute(JavaSquidSensor.java:84)
    at org.sonar.batch.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:57)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:58)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:50)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:83)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:192)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:241)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:236)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:234)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:226)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
    at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:106)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:79)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:171)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:128)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:63)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.sonar.java.se.ProgramPoint.<init>(ProgramPoint.java:42)
    at org.sonar.java.se.ProgramPoint.<init>(ProgramPoint.java:34)
    at org.sonar.java.bytecode.se.BytecodeEGWalker.handleBlockExit(BytecodeEGWalker.java:328)
    at org.sonar.java.bytecode.se.BytecodeEGWalker.execute(BytecodeEGWalker.java:141)
    at org.sonar.java.bytecode.se.BytecodeEGWalker.getMethodBehavior(BytecodeEGWalker.java:108)
    at org.sonar.java.se.xproc.BehaviorCache.get(BehaviorCache.java:77)
    at org.sonar.java.se.xproc.BehaviorCache.get(BehaviorCache.java:60)
    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.executeMethodInvocation(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:640)
    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.visit(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:512)
    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.execute(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:244)
    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.visitMethod(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:204)
    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.visitMethod(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:196)
    at org.sonar.java.se.SymbolicExecutionVisitor.execute(SymbolicExecutionVisitor.java:77)
    at org.sonar.java.se.SymbolicExecutionVisitor.visitNode(SymbolicExecutionVisitor.java:63)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:95)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:120)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:97)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:120)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:97)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanTree(SubscriptionVisitor.java:78)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanFile(SubscriptionVisitor.java:64)
    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:114)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:96)
    ... 56 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]
```

I have tried with different versions, like `3.1.1`, `3.3.0.60`, `3.4.0.905`, but still getting the same error.

Anyone suggestions how I can resolve this?

Comment: What is the version of SonarJava installed on your server?

Comment: What is your project structure? In which directory you executed `mvn sonar:sonar`?

Comment: V3.9 version of sonarjava i'm using

Comment: What is your project structure? In which directory you executed mvn sonar:sonar?

I'm executing in project root folder

structure of my project is 

Proj2(root)
submodule1
submodule2
.
.
.
submodule7